# Batch File : Not able to concatenate a loop counter value to a constant string

Tags: windows-7, batch

This is in continuation with the question here. [Batch Script: Concatenating multiple files in multiple folders into one file](https://superuser.com/q/926481/379767)

I have 20 files with name 'new.csv' in 20 folders in the same parent directory. I want to concatenate all of them into one file. So, I want to do it in two steps.

1. I am using XCOPY to copy each new.csv of each folder to new1, new2, new3 etc. in the parent folder. If I can do this, in my parent folder, I have 20 csvs, new1, new2..new20.csv.
2. Then, I can just do a `copy new*.csv final.csv`.  So, this is the code that I wrote to make the copies of each of these `new.csv` from each folder in the parent folder.

   ```
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set /a i=0
   FOR /D /R %%G in ("*") DO (

   cd %%G 
   set  /a i=i+1
   XCOPY new.csv ..\new%!i!%.csv )
   ```

The problem is in creating a new file. I want to create 20 files with names, new1.csv, new2.csv, new3.csv...new20.csv. The counter value is getting incremented, but I cannot append it to 'new'. Could you please help.

Comment: I know you've self-answered, but your question makes no sense. First you say you have 20 files all named new.csv that you want to concatenate into one file. Next you say you want to create 20 files with names new1.csv, new2.csv... This is clearly contradictory. Which of the two are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am sorry if it was unclear. I have tried to explain it.

Comment: Ok, got it. For the record you don't need this 2-step process but if you've got it working already that's good.

Comment: I knew it. Could you please share the easier method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
I am answering myself, with whatever worked for me. I replaced the last line like this.

```
 XCOPY new.csv ..\new_!i!.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full paths to the individual CSVs listed inside the consolidated CSV, use this:

```
for /r %f in (*.csv) do @echo "%f" >> New.csv && echo. >> New.csv && type "%f" >> New.csv && echo. >> New.csv && echo --- >> New.csv
```

If you just want the CSV contents, use this:

```
for /r %f in (*.csv) do @type "%f" >> New.csv && echo. >> New.csv
```

`echo.` adds a newline to the file and can be removed if not required to further shorten the command.

These commands have to be typed in the parent directory. If you're using them in a batch file just remember to double each % sign.